# How can I monitor the free space on a persistent disk in Google Compute Engine?

Tags: monitoring, google-compute-engine, disk

I've created a [persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/) in Google Compute Engine and attached it to an instance. What I am wondering however, is how can I monitor the free space on the disk? Can't see it either in the Google Cloud Console or from the `gcloud` tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you cannot use the Stackdriver Monitoring Agent, an alternative will be to use the gcloud command line tool to write to cloud logging.

Note that this is using a beta command, so may change in the future.

First, ensure that the logging beta commands are installed by typing:

```
gcloud beta logging
```

If it does not work, you can install with:

```
sudo gcloud components install beta
```

On your instance setup a cron job to run some script according to a schedule:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

Go to the bottom of the file and enter:

```
0 * * * * gcloud beta logging write disk_usage $(df / |  awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f 1 | tail -n 1)
```

This will run the command **gcloud beta logging write disk_usage $(df / |  awk '{print $5}' | cut -d '%' -f 1 | tail -n 1)** once an hour, which will write the % of used space to the disk_usage log.

Next go to [Logging](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer) and from the first drop down choose **Global** and from the second choose **disk_space**.

It is not a perfect solution, but it will work.

Comment: By disk_space, you mean disk_usage right? I think that should be the log's name. What is the log supposed to look like though? I get a JSON object containing the keys 'textPayload', 'insertId', 'resource', 'timestamp' and 'logName'. Not sure what to make of this info.

Comment: Also, I guess all the `gcloud` commands should be run on the instance to be monitored right?

Comment: @aknuds1 Yes, on the instance to be monitored.

Comment: I'm not sure if the `cut -d '%'` part makes sense btw, as I find it more enlightening if the % part stays, e.g. 42% makes it clear that the number represents disk usage. Also, it helps if the logging command prefix the log entry with the instance name, since there are typically several instances involved.

Comment: Depending on your setup, you may be better to put the gcloud command in a separate script and reference that in the crontab config.

Answer (score 7):

You can use (Google) Stackdriver monitoring: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/

If you install the [Monitoring Agent](https://app.google.stackdriver.com/settings/accounts/agent/) on your instance, the **Volume Free Space (Agent)** metric will then become available.

You can setup an alert to notify you at significant levels.

Note that the Agent is now only available with a **Premium** subscription.

Comment: I couldn't see how to monitor disk space in Stackdriver however, already using it.

Comment: It appears that Google have moved things around since I setup my dashboards, the Monitoring Agent is now only available with a __Premium__ subscription :-(

Comment: Ugh, that sucks 

Comment: @aknuds1 I have posted an alternative answer above.

Comment: Thanks, haven't tried it yet but it looks promising.

Answer (score 4):

If you have GCP VMs then you can monitor using the stackdriver agent and you'll need to add the following alert policy. It won't appear in the console until after a few hours of collecting info from your agents:

```
volume usage (agent)
```

[image]